# without cacheable false in layout magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, cache

Get quote data from block without `cacheable="false"`.

Marketplace doesn't accept `cacheable="false"` in layout.

It throws the varnish problem. How can resolve without `cacheable="false"`.

Quote subtotal can't get from block without `cachable="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, we can use `cacheable="false"` on a layout for session case - Customer page. And, some specific pages usually have the changes: Cart page and checkout page.

BUT, please avoid using `cacheable="false"`as we can. As we know, the whole page will be uncached. What happens if we add this value to a global layout. This will be a "big" performance issue.

We should think about Ajax way in most of the time.